# Ionic rxjs pipe function not getting called after http post

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, rxjs, rxjs6

I am using ionic 5

when I try to connect to firebase using post and get the response data and process the response using **pipe and tap** then it's not working. The log is not printing.

But when I replace the pipe with subscribe then it's working correctly and I can see the log correctly.

Please see the working and not working code below.

Can someone please help me to solve this issue. Thanks for your help.

**WORKING CODE**

```
 return this.http.post("https://project-name.firebaseio.com/offered-places.json", {
    ...newPlace, 
    id: null
  }).subscribe(resDate => {
    console.log(resDate);
  });
```

**NOT WORKING CODE**

```
return this.http.post("https://project-name.firebaseio.com/offered-places.json", {
    ...newPlace, 
    id: null
  }).pipe(
    tap(resData => {
      console.log(resData);
    })
  );
```

Comment: You have to subscribe to execute an observable

Comment: A bit more detail to your problem: If you have 0 subscriber listening to your observable, then your observable gets the emitted values but it does not push it into the pipes. That means: 0 subscriptions === no pipe operation is carried out.

Comment: Thanks for your command. Can you please tell me how I can add subscribers to the observable so it can push the value to the pipes. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments you have to call [subscribe](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/concepts/rxjs-primer#subscription) method

Here's the snippet which reproduces your cases and provides mentioned solution.

```js
const exampleObservable1 = rxjs.of([{}]);
const exampleObservable2 = rxjs.of([{}]);
const exampleObservable3 = rxjs.of([{}]);

console.log('working example');
exampleObservable1.subscribe(resDate => {
  console.log(resDate);
});

console.log('not working example');
exampleObservable2.pipe(
  rxjs.operators.tap(resData => {
    console.log(resData);
  }))

console.log('suggestion');
exampleObservable3.pipe(
  rxjs.operators.tap(resData => {
    console.log('tap', resData);
  })).subscribe(resDate => {
  console.log('subscription', resDate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks This works as expected. This is the code from my ionic code                                  return this.http.post<{ name: string }>("https://project-name.firebaseio.com/offered-places.json", {
        ...newPlace, 
        id: null
      })
      .pipe(
        tap(resData => {
          console.log("D" + resData);
        })).subscribe(resData => {
        console.log("Data in Subscribe:" + resData)
      });